# How should inflating go right way?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I need to have like several listviews on a scrollview which Android doesn't allow me to do so I decided to make it manually to simply inflate some listrows on a vertical LinearLayout, but everything goes not the right way

```
      private void fillData(final ViewGroup parent, final ArrayList<Person> array ){
          for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
             final View view = lf.inflate(R.layout.personal_listrow, parent,true);
             parent.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.background_light_darker));
             view.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.background_night_lighter));
              TextView tvName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
              TextView tvStatus=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
              TextView tvGender=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGender);

//fill textviews with info, set the onClickListeners and so on
}
```

So what I get - the view.setBackgroundColor paints parent as well .
parent is a vertical LinearLayout, view is  horizontal LinearLayout - it's strange that I don't paint inflated element only so please explain me why

The next thing - after I add something to array - 1st element changes and all the rest is with unchanged text. However, I walked through the code with debugger - it passes every element and sets text.

The clicklisteners works on the 1st element only..

Would you plz explain

here's vertical , parent layout - nothing special:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rodll"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

the inflateable listrow is nothing special also :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tvSt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tvName" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGender"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tvGender" />

  <com.andexert.library.RippleView 
           android:id="@+id/removeRipple"
           xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
           android:layout_width="35dp" 
           android:layout_height="35dp" 
           android:layout_marginRight="7.5dip" 
           android:padding="3dp"
           ripple:rv_alpha="255"
           ripple:rv_zoom="true"
           ripple:rv_zoomScale="0.8"
           ripple:rv_type="rectangle">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/remove_icon"

         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/remove" />
     </com.andexert.library.RippleView>

    <com.andexert.library.RippleView 
           android:id="@+id/addRipple"
           xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_width="35dp" 
           android:layout_height="35dp" 
           android:layout_marginRight="7.5dip" 
           android:padding="3dp"
           ripple:rv_alpha="255"
           ripple:rv_zoom="true"
           ripple:rv_zoomScale="0.8"
           ripple:rv_type="rectangle">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/add_icon"

         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/add" />
     </com.andexert.library.RippleView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So. what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps there is something missing; is there any reason you dont want a ListView?

Comment: because there are 5 Lists and I have to put them on a single ScrollView

Comment: Have you looked into ExpandableListView? Or even a ListView with a backing MergeCursor? In the latter,  you can combine several Cursors into a MergeCursor and that would act as the datasource for the ListView.

Comment: Look.. I need 5 several Lists.. divided, separate etc